# Combining two regex expressions into one

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that works: `ABC-[0-9]+`

I also have a regex: `DEF-[0-9]+`

But I don't get how to combine the two so it will match them both

I tried `ABC-[0-9]+ | DEF-[0-9]+` but it didn't really work...

This is all in Java regex if it matters.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't really work"? Can you give an example of it not working?

Comment: It simply didn't pick up the String. In hindsight, it was probably due to the spaces...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a regular expression that matches sequences that start with either `ABC` or `DEF`, try this:

```
(ABC|DEF)-[0-9]+
```

But except from the two space characters around `|`, your regular expression should match that too:

```
ABC-[0-9]+|DEF-[0-9]+
```

These two regular expressions match the same set of strings.

Comment: Won't that cause it to pull out only the ABC and DEF, being a Java regex?

Comment: @glowcoder: `(ABC|DEF)-[0-9]+` has capturing group 1, which will capture either `ABC` or `DEF`. Group 0 still exists (as always) and will match the entire string with the dash and digits. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html or http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg . That said, it's true that some regex frameworks will perform various special treatments when the pattern has _EXACTLY ONE_ capturing group, but as far as I know Java isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the two regexes, use an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html):

`(?>ABC-[0-9]+)|(?>DEF-[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `(ABC-[0-9]+)|(DEF-[0-9]+)`